Why do only the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian follow a boltzman distribution
Suppose I had a system with e.g. conserved impulse p, but no thermal equilibrium/fixed energy. Why is only the entropy of the distribution of eigenstates of the hamiltonian being maximized? (if p and H do not commute) Why not maximize the entropy over the eigenstates of p?

Do you know the MaxEnt principle? Depending on the constraints you impose, you get different distributions. You get the canonical distribution if you fix the average energy.

Yes I know, I was asking why it is the entropy of the energy distribution that is being maximized, and not some other distribution over eigenstates

Because the Hamiltonian is the generator of time translation, and it's evolution in time that brings systems into equilibrium.
